# What does 'TypeError: 'numpy.ndarray'?

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I am trying to fill in missing data using **KNN Imputation** and in concatenating the variables I get this error :-

```
Type Error: cannot concatenate object of type '<class 'numpy.ndarray'>'; only Series and DataFrame objs are valid
```

Comment: Help us help you - share the code the causes this error and the full traceback

Comment: Question is not clear probably will be flagged if you do not add code snippet

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask] and https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example. Error messages indicate that there is something wrong with your code. It is only possible to tell you in any detail what is wrong with code that you *actually show to us*. Also, you need to show [complete](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359146/why-should-i-post-complete-errors-why-isnt-the-message-itself-enough) error messages, copied and pasted (**not** typed from memory - and I know you did this time, because Python error messages write `TypeError` as one word).

Comment: That said, you can start the process by trying to *read and understand* the error message, [as is expected](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users). For example, you apparently understand what `concatenate` means, since that's how you describe what you were trying to do. So what exactly is unclear about the rest? I assume you understand what an `object` is, and what `valid` means, and what a `type` is. So, the concatenation wasn't possible because things weren't of compatible types for concatenation. Is it *surprising*? Why?

Comment: It's important to understand basic [debugging](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) skills as a programmer. These are part of the fundamentals, and you should expect to learn them well before trying to handle advanced topics like neural networks using massive third-party libraries.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.